# Calculating $w=\sqrt {-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking at the following:
$w=\sqrt {-i}$.

Rewriting
$w=\sqrt {-i}=\sqrt{\exp(-i\frac{\pi}{2}+ik2\pi )}$

$w=\exp(-i\frac{\pi}{4}) \exp(i k  \pi)$

How do I know which is the correct answer for $w$?

Let's suppose we take the principal branch.

Comment: You forgot to divide the second part of the exponent by $2$. The result is $\pm e^{-\pi i/4} = \pm \dfrac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: The $2\pi$ in your last line should probably have been a $\pi$. Are you looking at a particular (branch of the) square root? Two complex numbers square to $-i$; $\exp(-i \pi/4)$ and $\exp(3 i \pi/4)$. Edit: Too slow.

Comment: Draw a picture, see what numbers _should_ square up to $-i$.

Comment: What do you mean by **which**? You get a unique value of $\sqrt{-i}$ only if you decide on a particular *branch* of the square root function.

Comment: @mrf Can you please elaborate on the possible branches and what the answer would be in case of such a branch?

Comment: @mrf Edit: I am acquainted with the concept of branches only for the logarithm

Comment: @fuglede How can I look at a specific branch?

Comment: @fuglede  Let's suppose we take the principal branch. What can I then conclude?

Comment: @user104662: The principal square root of $re^{i\theta}$, $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$, $r > 0$, is $\sqrt{r}e^{i \theta/2}$. In your case, you can write $i = 1 \cdot e^{- \pi i /2}$, and so the principal square root is $e^{-\pi i/4}$.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct. The numbers you have found are $\pm( \frac{\sqrt2}{2} -i\frac{\sqrt2}{2})$. There is not a natural single value.

Comment: Thanks. But by using branches, I can make it a single value. That is what I am looking for, but I don't know how to do that. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Like mrf comments above, I would like to decide on a particular branch.

Answer (score 0):

"How do I know which is the correct answer for w?"

By definition of square root, $w^2=-i$. BTW, how many solutions?

Answer (score -1):

$$-i=\cos{3\pi/2}+i\sin{3\pi/2}=\exp{i(3\pi/2)} \\
\sqrt{-i}=[\exp{i(3\pi/2)}]^{1/2}=\exp{i(3\pi/4)}=\frac{i-1}{\sqrt{2}}$$