# image of the Upper Half Plane \ $[0,i]$ under $w=\sqrt{z^2 +1}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am looking the image of the Upper Half Plane excluding the line segment $[0,i]$ for the transformation $w=\sqrt{z^2 +1}$.

What I did so far is:

*image of $z\mapsto z^2 $ is: entire complex plane excluding line segment $[-1,\infty]$

*image of $z^2\mapsto z^2+1$ i: entire complex plane excluding line segment $ [0,\infty]$

*image of $z^2+1\mapsto \sqrt{z^2+1}$ is: Upper half plane

### ${\bf Conclusion }$: image is Upper half plane

Is my approach correct? If not what should I do different?

Comment: The upper half-plane does not include its boundary $\mathbb{R}$, so the image under $z\mapsto z^2$ of the indicated domain is $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,+\infty)$, not $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,0]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, but when following that logic it should be $\mathbb{C}  \setminus   (\infty,\infty), $ right?

Comment: @DanielFischer  EDIT: I mean $\mathbb{C} $ \  $(-\infty,\infty)$

Comment: No, $(it)^2 = -t^2$, which for $t > 1$ gives you the points in the upper half-plane (minus $[0,i]$) that are mapped to $(-\infty,-1)$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, I changed it now in my question. Can you please commment on whether the answer/ approach is correct now?

Comment: The approach was correct from the start, and now we've eliminated the errors, so what we've been left with are minor points. Two problems: 1. You forgot to update your conclusion text, and 2. You have two choices for the branch of the square root, for one the image is the upper half-plane, for the other, it is the lower half-plane; you should mention that.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your feedback. Your 2nd point is a point is still unclear to me (also asked it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644795/calculating-w-sqrt-i) ). How should I look at these branches? And what do they do? (P.s: I know it for the logarithm; you cannot 'walk around' 0 there)

Comment: The branch point is the same phenomenon. If you walk around $0$ once, you get the negative of the value you started from. Let $z(t) = e^{it}$, so letting $t$ range from $0$ to $2\pi$ walks around $0$ once. If you start with $\sqrt{z(0)} = 1$, a continuous square root function must have $\sqrt{z(t)} = e^{it/2}$ for all $t$. Thus for $t \nearrow 2\pi$, you have $\sqrt{z(t)} \to e^{i\pi} = -1$. But here, we are not concerned with branch points. All that matters is that every $z\neq 0$ is the square of _two_ complex numbers, $z = w^2 = (-w)^2$. So if you have a function $f$ with $f(z)^2 = z^2+1$,

Comment: then $g(z) = -f(z)$ is another such function. You just need to say which one you denote with $\sqrt{z^2+1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you. I was actually addressing this: ''You have two choices for the branch of the square root, for one the image is the upper half-plane, for the other, it is the lower half-plane.'' How do you know: 1. that there are 2 choices? ; and:   2. Why can you say: ''for one the image is the upper half-plane, for the other, it is the lower half-plane''?

Comment: I know that there are two choices because every nonzero complex number has two different square roots. The two choices differ by a factor of $-1$. But continuity determines the choice in the entire domain once the value in one point is chosen, so I only have two choices, not two for every point. I know 2., because $s\colon w \mapsto w^2$ maps the upper half-plane (biholomorphically) to $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,+\infty)$, and since $s$ is even, it maps the lower half-plane (also biholomorphcally, of course) to the same domain. You have the same phenomenon already in the real situation. Say you

Comment: want a function $r \colon (0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property $r(x)^2 = x$ for all $x\in (0,+\infty)$. You can choose whether $r(x) < 0$ for all $x$, or $r(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends upon where you make the branch cut.  Your approach is essentially correct, if you take the branch cut to be along the positive real axis.  Another common choice of branch cut is along the negative real axis.  This leads to the right half plane but you have the interesting situation that part of the boundary of the image is included.

In both of the images below, the red portion is the artificially excluded segment from $0$ to $i$.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Since the image of the upper half-plane minus $[0,i]$ under $z\mapsto z^2+1$ is $\mathbb{C}\setminus [0,\infty)$, there is no choice where to place the branch cut of the square root so that $\sqrt{z^2+1}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{H}\setminus (0,i]$.